# Volume of intersection of non-concentric cylinder and sphere

Tags: calculus

I want to calculate volume of intersection of a sphere and cylinder but they are not concentric. Sphere has a radius of 1 and located at (0,0,R+h). Cylinder has a radius of R and centered at origin. I know there is some way to use integration but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Giving us the center and radius of your cylinder does not specify it uniquely. Which way is it oriented?

Comment: My mistake. The cylinder has the equation x^2+z^2=R^2